# Spring-XD fail to execute shell command

Tags: java, python, spring, spring-xd

Python / SpringXD is not the combination resulting in the error written in my previous post, the shell of springxd alone can't succeed executing on my system

The stream definition:

```
trigger --cron='0 */1 * * * *' | shell --command='ls' | log
```

here is the error message:

```
2016-04-19T16:06:06-0400 1.3.1.SNAP ERROR inbound.awef-p2_7-log.0-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 redis.RedisMessageBus$1 - Failed to deliver message; retries exhausted; message sent to queue 'ERRORS:awef-p2_7-log.0' org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream closed
2016-04-19T16:06:17-0400 1.3.1.SNAP ERROR inbound.test-ls.0-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 process.ShellCommandProcessor - Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.springframework.xd.extension.process.ShellCommandProcessor.send(ShellCommandProcessor.java:156) [spring-xd-extension-process-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.xd.extension.process.ShellCommandProcessor.sendAndReceive(ShellCommandProcessor.java:171) [spring-xd-extension-process-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally twick the call to python through a groovy script:

stream def:

```
trigger --cron='0 0/1 * * * *' | script --script=file:/.../testjobpython.groovy | null
```

code groovy:

```
String[] pythonCmd = ["/usr/bin/python2.7","/.../testjobpython.py"]
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pythonCmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this could be because of the `sys.exit()` call in your python code. What happens when you don't call `sys.exit()` ?

Comment: Hi, I removed it, but still have the same error. Thanks